# I am getting, WSO2 maven Build failure Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (default) on project with IOException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wso2-esb

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.586 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-04T10:38:08+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/113M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (default) on project ProjectSynapseConfigs: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "D:\location\project\ProjectSynapseConfigs\target\capp"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
```

When I run the maven script manually through command prompt with debug mode I get the below error.

```
    Detailed error:[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (default) on project ProjectnameSynapseConfigs: Command execution failed.: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "D:\codelocation\ProjectSynapseConfigs\target\capp"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (default) on project ProjectSynapseConfigs: Command execution failed.
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
            at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:350)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
            ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "D:\codelocation\ProjectSynapseConfigs\target\capp"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
            at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
            at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
            at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:246)
            at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:302)
            at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:149)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:589)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:335)
            ... 22 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
            at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
            at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
            ... 29 more
```

Since it is stating IOException, is it expecting any file or entries to be made change. 
    Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.wso2.esb.projectSynapseConfigs</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectSynapseConfigs</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>projectSynapseConfigs</name>
  <description>projectSynapseConfigs</description>
  <build>
    <directory>target/capp</directory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>mvn</executable>
              <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
              <arguments>
                <argument>clean</argument>
                <argument>install</argument>
                <argument>-Dmaven.test.skip=${maven.test.skip}</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration />
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <buildcommands />
          <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.esb.project.nature</projectnature>
          </projectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>wso2-esb-proxy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>proxy</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>pom-gen</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactLocation>.</artifactLocation>
              <typeList>${artifact.types}</typeList>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration />
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <properties>
    <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
    <CApp.type>bpel/workflow=zip,lib/registry/filter=jar,webapp/jaxws=war,lib/library/bundle=jar,service/dataservice=dbs,synapse/local-entry=xml,synapse/proxy-service=xml,carbon/application=car,registry/resource=zip,lib/dataservice/validator=jar,synapse/endpoint=xml,web/application=war,lib/carbon/ui=jar,service/axis2=aar,synapse/sequence=xml,synapse/configuration=xml,wso2/gadget=dar,lib/registry/handlers=jar,lib/synapse/mediator=jar</CApp.type>
  </properties>
</project>
```

I am using Java 1.8 64 bit,
Windows 64 bit OS
maven  3.5.0

Comment: You have to run mvn in the project root not in a subdirectory

Comment: Yes I run in my root only but, I don't know how the error is showing from inside. the target folder is creating when we run the root only. the pom.xml is from root.

Comment: In your Pom you see that is called in a target directory

Comment: Yes, I run from the root directory only and still getting the same error. Why in pom.xml we have mentioned child directory is to delete the folders and create again.

Comment: But here you can see that it will run in subdir: `<executable>mvn</executable>
              <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>`

Comment: Ok what is expected to be modified here?

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do with this code